# Firebase node.js cannot read cloud API private key file

Tags: node.js, firebase, api-key, google-cloud-console

I am using Firebase as my server. I need to use a Google Cloud API so I have the following in my `functions/src/index.ts` file:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')

const key = require('./auth.json')
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, scopes)
const view_id = 'XXXXXXX'

process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = './auth.json'
```

[I am following this example](https://flaviocopes.com/google-api-authentication/#service-to-service-api). But when I try to deploy I get the error that

```
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './auth.json'
```

The file is located at `functions/src/auth.json`. How do I solve this?

Comment: Try const path = require(“path”); then set your credentials env to path.join(__dirname, “auth.json”); might be the issue.

Comment: First I would not recommend to add private information in the file like this. You might want to move all the information from .auth.json to .env file of your project. Can you paste auth.json file by removing critical information, just want to see how you are exporting it.

Comment: yeah I moved to env using https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env and it's working